# PHP Mailer Autoloader

Tags: php, phpmailer

i just downloaded (manually) and installed phpmailer on my shared hosting account and when i go to

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

i notice that in the library i downloaded there is no PHPMailerAutoload.php, do i need to make this file ? i know it loads the dependancies for phpmailer to work but i cant find any answers on where this file is located or how to create it.

I have also tried the code below so i don't need to use the autoload file and manually call the required files but this doesn't work either. I turned errors on and get nothing from php error log that there is an issue:

```
<?php
define('PATH', dirname(__FILE__));


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/home/mycpanel/public_html/domain.com/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/mycpanel/public_html/domain.com/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/home/mycpanel/public_html/domain.com/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Anyone have a clue what i need to do ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you can't use Composer? ~ https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading

Comment: i used composer on my Mac and installed it via terminal and it still didnt download any phpmailerautoload file

Comment: With composer, you just include the `vendor/autoload.php` file

Comment: ive used composer before and integrated with soap apis/rest apis etc so i understand that. i am not using composer, is there any way to do this without composer.

Comment: Also wondering this, as I am unable to use composer in the current project.